# Macbook Pro Can't Open Site Beside Google, Youtube, Facebook

Tags: macbook-pro, wifi, internet

I have macbook pro, with MacOS High Sierra. The thing is, i can't connect to any websites beside those on the title, but only when i connected to a specific Wi-Fi in my office, and happened on all browser. I have no problem when i connected to my own Wi-Fi at home. And this is only happen to my macbook, my phone using same Wi-Fi but have no problem. I did follow many solutions like add google dns, flushdns, turning off ipv6, etc but none of them working. I even try to look for solution using my phone, since i can't open single link on google. Pls help, been through this for past few weeks...

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you talked to your network administrator in the office about this? What kind of error do you get when you access other sites? Does `ping 151.101.113.67` (www.cnn.com) (or pinging any other apparently unreachable server via its IP address) in Terminal work?

Comment: I tried to ping 151.101.113.67 just now, but it said "no route to host"...

Comment: So it's not (or not only) a DNS issue. Can you compare the network settings your Mac gets to those your iPhone gets on this WiFi?

Comment: I'm using android btw... both in mac & phone get the IP using DHCP. No proxy... i forgot to state what kind of error i got when open websites. i'm using chrome, said the site can't be reached...

Comment: I'm asking my friend who connected to same Wi-Fi, but she didn't get the problem. She's not using Mac tho...

Comment: The android device and the Mac don‘t seem to be connected to the same network, is this intentional?

Comment: they're in the same network... both of the devices...

Comment: Strange, they get IP addresses from two totally different ranges. Can you add two screenshots which show the network name the devices connect to? Or at least go back and verify that they indeed connect to the same network?

Comment: The IP address 169.254.XXX.XXX is a *self-assigned IP* or *[automatic private IP address](https://www.webopedia.com/TERM/A/APIPA.html)*.  You get this when you don't get an IP address from the DHCP server.  See this [post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/282908/119271) for more detail

Comment: Also, if it's happening at work, more than likely there's some sort of authentication going on.  See this [post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/302390/mac-doesnt-connect-to-university-wi-fi/302406#302406) for more details.

Comment: Yeb, they're in the same network.... http://imgur.com/JtprdYa & http://imgur.com/QK4lhPC

Comment: For whatever reason your Mac only gets an IPv6 address from the WiFi network. If this has worked before: do you remember any changes on your Mac after which is stopped working? And I still think you should to whoever is in charge of the WiFi and tell them that you don‘t seem to get an IPv4 address when joining the network.

Comment: Being connected to a WiFi network only means you're *associated* with that AP - in other words, it accepted your WiFi credentials.  It **does not** mean you're connected to the network; you can verify this with an IP address.  If you get the 169.254.XXX.XXX address, *you aren't connected to the network.*

Comment: The Wi-Fi also connected to my phone, so I can use my phone for tethering (via USB, no mobile data) and that works perfectly. I can open all websites without any problem.

Answer (score 4):

I know this question is a bit old and hopefully the OP has already solved there issue but for those who are finding themselves with the same issue I'll leave what I found others doing and what worked for them and then I'll put what worked for me.

The issue seems to arise from the Mac trying to self-assign itself an IP.

1. If you're experiencing this issue, the first thing I would try is renew the Lease in your network preferences panel: `System Preferences > Network > Advanced > TCP/IP > Renew Lease`
2. Other's have also said that deleting their Wi-Fi Prefered Networks `... > Advanced > Wi-Fi` fixed it for them.
3. Other's mentioned having to delete the Wi-Fi Service in `Network` and re-adding it
4. Other's suggested changing DNS to Google or OpenDNS (8.8.8.8 or 8.8.4.4 for Google)

Another solution that worked well for most was to flush the DNS:

**Mac OS X Yosemite and later**
`sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder`

**Mac OS X Yosemite v10.10 through v10.10.3**
`sudo discoveryutil mdnsflushcache`

**Mac OS X Mavericks, Mountain Lion and Lion**
`sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder`

**Mac OS X Snow Leopard**
`sudo dscacheutil -flushcache`

The most common one I saw was the suggestion of going into finder and navigating to `/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration` (you can get their by pressing CMD + SHIFT + G) and deleting the following files:

- `com.apple.airport.preferences.plist`
- `com.apple.network.identification.plist` (or `com.apple.network.eapolclient.configuration.plist` depending on OS version)
- `NetworkInterfaces.plist`
- `preferences.plist`

And then after deleting the files reboot your computer and try connecting to your network.

Another suggestion was the firewall but because my firewall was already turned off I didn't try this method.

None of those worked for me, however. What did work for me when none of the other suggestions did was setting my IPV4 to manual (`System Preferences > Network > Advanced > TCP/IP`) and filling in the information as such:

```
IPv4 Address: 192.168.0.32
Subnet Mask: 255.255.0.0
Router: 192.168.0.1
```

This method requires that you know the base of the IPv4 Address. For this, you'll need another computer on your network and type `ifconfig | grep inet` into terminal for Mac or if your other computer is Windows you can do `ipconig` and find it. It usually always starts with `192.168` which can then be followed by (most commonly off of experience) 0, 1, or two. The last part of the IP I chose at random but needed it to be a value high enough that it wouldn't conflict with another device.

You can grab the router ip of this other device too. I believe most phones will display the information somewhere.

**IMPORTANT NOTE** is to mention that if you "played" with the IPv6 you'll need to set this back to automatic

Comment: Be careful, when setting up a static ip address, you could use the ip address of someone else like your boss or worse your CEO.  The first person of the day who uses the address wins.